# Как присвоить индексы?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Есть такой код, на данный момент индексы присваиваются подряд, т.е. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Как сделать так, чтобы индексы присваивались таким образом 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3

Т.е. максимальный индекс = 3, если достигнут максимальный, то начать с 0

Comment: `i % 4` ........

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach((div, i) => div.dataset.index = i % 4);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].setAttribute('data-index', i % 4);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```